# What might cause the fully qualified name of a table in a SQL Server stored procedure to be overridden when executed?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

A client has several SQL Server stored procedures in one database, `Customer`, that reference tables in another database, called `MutualFunds`.

Yesterday, their on-site admin made a copy of the `MutualFunds` database, which he named `BACKUP-MutualFunds`. When these stored procedures are called, the message 942 is thrown:

> Database BACKUP-MutualFunds cannot be opened because it is offline.

That indicates to me that the stored procedures are attempting to query `BACKUP-MutualFunds.dbo.tablename`, but the table references within the stored procedures are qualified names, i.e., `MutualFunds.dbo.tablename`. I have never seen this before and am hoping that someone may have come across something similar.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: I guess the stored procedures also has copy in backup database, do you check the step settings of agent job? which database is selected in the Transact-SQL script step

Comment: The database selected in the Transact-SQL step of the agent job is the db where the stored procedure lives, i.e. Customer. The backup database is not referenced and the proper database is referenced in the qualified table name within the stored procedure itself.